# seek from end of a istringstream fails

Tags: c++, stl, istringstream, seekg

Here is a minimalist code :

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
    {
    std::string str = "spam" ;
    std::istringstream isz( str ) ;
    isz.seekg( 1,std::ios_base::beg ) ; std::cout << isz.fail() ;
    isz.seekg( 1,std::ios_base::cur ) ; std::cout << isz.fail() ;
    isz.seekg( 1,std::ios_base::end ) ; std::cout << isz.fail() ;
    return 0 ;
    }
```

I get `001` meaning the last `seekg` failed.
I the same with linux/g++ and win/MSVC.
I can't find such limitation in C++/stl documentation...
Any idea ?
Thx

Comment: _"I get `001`"_ means what actually?

Comment: "001" is the string I get on stdout : it is the concatenation of the 3  " cout << isz.fail() ".  
Each one gives 0 (meaning false = not failed) or 1 (meaning true = failed).

Comment: Unrelated `fail` just returns true or false. If you inspect the individual fail bits (and `boolalpha` can make the output more readable) you can more precisely pinpoint the actual failure.

Comment: Did you mean to inspect the `eof()` flag rather than `fail()`?? I don't see why `isz.seekg( 1,std::ios_base::end )` should set the `fail()` flag?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I missed a point :
When I call `seekg( 1,std::ios_base::end )`, I try go 1 char **after** the end (which fails as it should).
I have to call `seekg( -1,std::ios_base::end )` to go 1 char **before** the end.